# Streamripper recording only weird noise

Tags: raspbian, audio

I am running Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi. Anyone has tried streamripper?

When I use streamripper to record any online radio station, streamripper only records weird noise, no matter what url I put. I think it has to do something with pulseaudio, althougth I didn't configured it.

I also posted this question on streamripper forum...

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Stream ripper simply grabs data in the stream. So Pulse audio has nothing to do with it except when you play back the data. So grab the files that were stream ripped and play them on your regular computer to see if the data was correctly grabbed.